# How to get the selected Row values on SelectionChanged Event for Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductID" Width="70" Binding="{Binding ProductId}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MeasurementId" Width="100" Binding="{Binding MesurementID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Price}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

my event: private void Grid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {  }
if I selected on any row how to get all the column values..please help me

Comment: So, how are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the SelectionChangedEventArgs. It has AddedItems property which contains the items selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to retrieve DataGridRow combo box triggered in

```
private void ComboBoxRight_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox    = (ComboBox) sender;
        DataGridRow row      = (DataGridRow) dataGrid.ContainerFromElement(comboBox);
        int rowIndex         = row.GetIndex();
        YourModel gridModel    = (YourModel) dataGrid.Items[rowIndex];
    }
```